# Implementing a recursive parser without try

Tags: parsing, haskell, recursion, parsec

I am trying to parse an XML dump of Wikipedia to find certain links on each page using the Haskell Parsec library.  Links are denoted by double brackets: `texttext[[link]]texttext`. To simplify the scenario as much as possible, let's say I am looking for the first link not enclosed in double curly braces (which can be nested): `{{  {{ [[Wrong Link]] }} [[Wrong Link]]  }} [[Right Link]]`. I have written a parser to discard links which are enclosed in non-nested double braces:

```
import Text.Parsec

getLink :: String -> Either ParseError String
getLink = parse linkParser "Links"

linkParser = do
    beforeLink
    link <- many $ noneOf "]"
    string "]]"
    return link

beforeLink = manyTill (many notLink) (try $ string "[[")

notLink = try doubleCurlyBrac <|> (many1 normalText)

normalText = noneOf "[{"
           <|> notFollowedByItself '['
           <|> notFollowedByItself '{'

notFollowedByItself c = try ( do x <- char c
                                 notFollowedBy $ char c
                                 return x)

doubleCurlyBrac = between (string "{{") (string "}}") (many $ noneOf "}")

getLinkTest = fmap getLink testList
    where testList = ["   [[rightLink]]   "                            --Correct link is found
                     , "  {{    [[Wrong_Link]]    }}  [[rightLink]]"   --Correct link is found
                     , "  {{  {{ }} [[Wrong_Link]] }} [[rightLink]]" ] --Wrong link is found
```

I have tried making the `doubleCurlyBrac` parser recursive to also discard links in nested curly braces, without success:

```
doubleCurlyBrac = between (string "{{") (string "}}") betweenBraces
        where betweenBraces = doubleCurlyBrac <|> (many $ try $ noneOf "}")
```

This parser stops consuming input after the first `}}`, rather than the final one, in a nested example. Is there an elegant way to write a recursive parser to (in this case) correctly ignore links in nested double curly braces? Also, can it be done without using `try`? I have found that since `try` does not consume input, it often causes the parser to hang on unexpected, ill-formed input.

Comment: How do you want `"{{ab}cd}}"` parsed?

Comment: A more detailed grammar description would be helpful.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė In that example, the parser should pick out `ab}cd`.

Comment: @JohnG it should, but the `noneOf "}"` will stop after `ab`.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė I was trying to simplify as much as possible for the sake of clarity in the question. My actual code was something like `many (noneOf "}" <|> notFollowedByIteslf '}')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more direct version that doesn't use a custom lexer.  It does use `try` though, and I don't see how to avoid it here.  The problem is that it seems we need a non-committing look ahead to distinguish double brackets from single brackets; `try` is for non-committing look ahead.

The high level approach is that same as in
[my first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19331687/470844). I've been careful
to make the three node parsers commute -- making the code more robust
to change -- by using both `try` and `notFollowedBy`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}
import Text.Parsec hiding (string)
import qualified Text.Parsec
import Control.Applicative ((<$>) , (<*) , (<*>))
import Control.Monad (forM_)
import Data.List (find)

import Debug.Trace

----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Token parsers.

llink , rlink , lbrace , rbrace :: Parsec String u String
[llink , rlink , lbrace , rbrace] = reserved
reserved = map (try . Text.Parsec.string) ["[[" , "]]" , "{{" , "}}"]

----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Node parsers.

-- Link, braces, or string.
data Node = L [Node] | B [Node] | S String deriving Show

nodes :: Parsec String u [Node]
nodes = many node

node :: Parsec String u Node
node = link <|> braces <|> string

link , braces , string :: Parsec String u Node
link   = L <$> between llink  rlink  nodes
braces = B <$> between lbrace rbrace nodes
string = S <$> many1 (notFollowedBy (choice reserved) >> anyChar)

----------------------------------------------------------------------

parseNodes :: String -> Either ParseError [Node]
parseNodes = parse (nodes <* eof) "<no file>"

----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Tests.

getLink :: [Node] -> Maybe Node
getLink = find isLink where
  isLink (L _) = True
  isLink _     = False

parseLink :: String -> Either ParseError (Maybe Node)
parseLink = either Left (Right . getLink) . parseNodes

testList = [ "   [[rightLink]]   "
           , "  {{    [[Wrong_Link]]    }}  [[rightLink]]"
           , "  {{  {{ }} [[Wrong_Link]] }} [[rightLink]]"
           , " [[{{[[someLink]]}}]] {{}} {{[[asdf]]}}"
           -- Pathalogical example from comments.
           , "{{ab}cd}}"
           -- A more pathalogical example.
           , "{ [ { {asf{[[[asdfa]]]}aasdff ] ] ] {{[[asdf]]}}asdf" 
           -- No top level link.
           , "{{[[Wrong_Link]]asdf[[WRong_Link]]{{}}}}{{[[[[Wrong]]]]}}"
           -- Too many '{{'.
           , "{{ {{ {{ [[ asdf ]] }} }}"
           -- Too many '}}'.
           , "{{ {{ [[ asdf ]] }} }} }}"
           -- Too many '[['.
           , "[[ {{ [[{{[[asdf]]}}]]}}"
           ]

main =
  forM_ testList $ \ t -> do
  putStrLn $ "Test: ^" ++ t ++ "$"
  let parses = ( , ) <$> parseNodes t <*> parseLink t
      printParses (n , l) = do
        putStrLn $ "Nodes: " ++ show n
        putStrLn $ "Link: " ++ show l
      printError = putStrLn . show
  either printError printParses parses
  putStrLn ""
```

The output is the same in the non-error cases:

```
Test: ^   [[rightLink]]   $
Nodes: [S "   ",L [S "rightLink"],S "   "]
Link: Just (L [S "rightLink"])

Test: ^  {{    [[Wrong_Link]]    }}  [[rightLink]]$
Nodes: [S "  ",B [S "    ",L [S "Wrong_Link"],S "    "],S "  ",L [S "rightLink"]]
Link: Just (L [S "rightLink"])

Test: ^  {{  {{ }} [[Wrong_Link]] }} [[rightLink]]$
Nodes: [S "  ",B [S "  ",B [S " "],S " ",L [S "Wrong_Link"],S " "],S " ",L [S "rightLink"]]
Link: Just (L [S "rightLink"])

Test: ^ [[{{[[someLink]]}}]] {{}} {{[[asdf]]}}$
Nodes: [S " ",L [B [L [S "someLink"]]],S " ",B [],S " ",B [L [S "asdf"]]]
Link: Just (L [B [L [S "someLink"]]])

Test: ^{{ab}cd}}$
Nodes: [B [S "ab}cd"]]
Link: Nothing

Test: ^{ [ { {asf{[[[asdfa]]]}aasdff ] ] ] {{[[asdf]]}}asdf$
Nodes: [S "{ [ { {asf{",L [S "[asdfa"],S "]}aasdff ] ] ] ",B [L [S "asdf"]],S "asdf"]
Link: Just (L [S "[asdfa"])

Test: ^{{[[Wrong_Link]]asdf[[WRong_Link]]{{}}}}{{[[[[Wrong]]]]}}$
Nodes: [B [L [S "Wrong_Link"],S "asdf",L [S "WRong_Link"],B []],B [L [L [S "Wrong"]]]]
Link: Nothing
```

but the parse error messages are not as informative in the cases of
unmatched openings:

```
Test: ^{{ {{ {{ [[ asdf ]] }} }}$
"<no file>" (line 1, column 26):
unexpected end of input
expecting "[[", "{{", "]]" or "}}"

Test: ^{{ {{ [[ asdf ]] }} }} }}$
"<no file>" (line 1, column 26):
unexpected "}}"

Test: ^[[ {{ [[{{[[asdf]]}}]]}}$
"<no file>" (line 1, column 25):
unexpected end of input
expecting "[[", "{{", "]]" or "}}"
```

and I couldn't figure out how to fix them.

Answer (score 1):

My solution does not use `try`, but is relatively complicated: I used
your question as an excuse to learn how to create a lexer in
Parsec without using 
[`makeTokenParser`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.3/docs/Text-Parsec-Token.html#v%3amakeTokenParser) :D I avoid `try` because the only look ahead happens in the lexer (`tokenize`), where the various bracket pairs are identified.

The high level idea is that we treat `{{`, `}}`, `[[`, and `]]` as
special tokens and parse the input into an AST.  You didn't specify
the grammar precisely, so I chose a simple one that generates your
examples:

```
node ::= '{{' node* '}}'
       | '[[' node* ']]'
       | string
string ::= <non-empty string without '{{', '}}', '[[', or ']]'>
```

I parse an input string into a list of nodes. The first top-level
link (`[[`) node, if any, is the link you're looking for.

The approach I've taken should be relatively robust to grammar
changes.  E.g., if you want to allow only strings inside links, then
change `'[[' node* ']]'` to `'[[' string ']]'`. (In the code

```
link = L <$> between llink  rlink  nodes
```

becomes

```
link = L <$> between llink  rlink  string
```

).

The code is fairly long, but mostly straightforward. Most of it
concerns creating the token stream (lexing) and parsing the individual
tokens.  After this, the actual `Node` parsing is very simple.

Here it is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}
import Text.Parsec hiding (char , string)
import Text.Parsec.Pos (updatePosString , updatePosChar)
import Control.Applicative ((<$>) , (<*) , (<*>))
import Control.Monad (forM_)
import Data.List (find)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Lexing.

-- Character or punctuation.
data Token = C Char | P String deriving Eq

instance Show Token where
  show (C c) = [c]
  show (P s) = s

tokenize :: String -> [Token]
tokenize [] = []
tokenize [c] = [C c]
tokenize (c1:c2:cs) = case [c1,c2] of
  "[[" -> ts
  "]]" -> ts
  "{{" -> ts
  "}}" -> ts
  _    -> C c1 : tokenize (c2:cs)
  where
    ts = P [c1,c2] : tokenize cs

----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Token parsers.

-- We update the 'sourcePos' while parsing the tokens.  Alternatively,
-- we could have annotated the tokens with positions above in
-- 'tokenize', and then here we would use 'token' instead of
-- 'tokenPrim'.
llink , rlink , lbrace , rbrace :: Parsec [Token] u Token
[llink , rlink , lbrace , rbrace] =
  map (t . P) ["[[" , "]]" , "{{" , "}}"]
  where
    t x = tokenPrim show update match where
      match y = if x == y then Just x else Nothing
      update pos (P s) _ = updatePosString pos s

char :: Parsec [Token] u Char
char = tokenPrim show update match where
  match (C c) = Just c
  match (P _) = Nothing
  update pos (C c) _ = updatePosChar pos c

----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Node parsers.

-- Link, braces, or string.
data Node = L [Node] | B [Node] | S String deriving Show

nodes :: Parsec [Token] u [Node]
nodes = many node

node :: Parsec [Token] u Node
node = link <|> braces <|> string

link , braces , string :: Parsec [Token] u Node
link   = L <$> between llink  (rlink <?> "]]")  nodes
braces = B <$> between lbrace (rbrace <?> "}}") nodes
string = S <$> many1 char

----------------------------------------------------------------------

parseNodes :: String -> Either ParseError [Node]
parseNodes = parse (nodes <* eof) "<no file>" . tokenize

----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Tests.

getLink :: [Node] -> Maybe Node
getLink = find isLink where
  isLink (L _) = True
  isLink _     = False

parseLink :: String -> Either ParseError (Maybe Node)
parseLink = either Left (Right . getLink) . parseNodes

testList = [ "   [[rightLink]]   "
           , "  {{    [[Wrong_Link]]    }}  [[rightLink]]"
           , "  {{  {{ }} [[Wrong_Link]] }} [[rightLink]]"
           , " [[{{[[someLink]]}}]] {{}} {{[[asdf]]}}"
           -- Pathalogical example from comments.
           , "{{ab}cd}}"
           -- A more pathalogical example.
           , "{ [ { {asf{[[[asdfa]]]}aasdff ] ] ] {{[[asdf]]}}asdf" 
           -- No top level link.
           , "{{[[Wrong_Link]]asdf[[WRong_Link]]{{}}}}{{[[[[Wrong]]]]}}"
           -- Too many '{{'.
           , "{{ {{ {{ [[ asdf ]] }} }}"
           -- Too many '}}'.
           , "{{ {{ [[ asdf ]] }} }} }}"
           -- Too many '[['.
           , "[[ {{ [[{{[[asdf]]}}]]}}"
           ]

main =
  forM_ testList $ \ t -> do
  putStrLn $ "Test: ^" ++ t ++ "$"
  let parses = ( , ) <$> parseNodes t <*> parseLink t
      printParses (n , l) = do
        putStrLn $ "Nodes: " ++ show n
        putStrLn $ "Link: " ++ show l
      printError = putStrLn . show
  either printError printParses parses
  putStrLn ""
```

The output from `main` is:

```
Test: ^   [[rightLink]]   $
Nodes: [S "   ",L [S "rightLink"],S "   "]
Link: Just (L [S "rightLink"])

Test: ^  {{    [[Wrong_Link]]    }}  [[rightLink]]$
Nodes: [S "  ",B [S "    ",L [S "Wrong_Link"],S "    "],S "  ",L [S "rightLink"]]
Link: Just (L [S "rightLink"])

Test: ^  {{  {{ }} [[Wrong_Link]] }} [[rightLink]]$
Nodes: [S "  ",B [S "  ",B [S " "],S " ",L [S "Wrong_Link"],S " "],S " ",L [S "rightLink"]]
Link: Just (L [S "rightLink"])

Test: ^ [[{{[[someLink]]}}]] {{}} {{[[asdf]]}}$
Nodes: [S " ",L [B [L [S "someLink"]]],S " ",B [],S " ",B [L [S "asdf"]]]
Link: Just (L [B [L [S "someLink"]]])

Test: ^{{ab}cd}}$
Nodes: [B [S "ab}cd"]]
Link: Nothing

Test: ^{ [ { {asf{[[[asdfa]]]}aasdff ] ] ] {{[[asdf]]}}asdf$
Nodes: [S "{ [ { {asf{",L [S "[asdfa"],S "]}aasdff ] ] ] ",B [L [S "asdf"]],S "asdf"]
Link: Just (L [S "[asdfa"])

Test: ^{{[[Wrong_Link]]asdf[[WRong_Link]]{{}}}}{{[[[[Wrong]]]]}}$
Nodes: [B [L [S "Wrong_Link"],S "asdf",L [S "WRong_Link"],B []],B [L [L [S "Wrong"]]]]
Link: Nothing

Test: ^{{ {{ {{ [[ asdf ]] }} }}$
"<no file>" (line 1, column 26):
unexpected end of input
expecting }}

Test: ^{{ {{ [[ asdf ]] }} }} }}$
"<no file>" (line 1, column 24):
unexpected }}
expecting end of input

Test: ^[[ {{ [[{{[[asdf]]}}]]}}$
"<no file>" (line 1, column 25):
unexpected end of input
expecting ]]
```